# How do I disable caching of dashboards while setting up DHIS 2?

Tags: dhis2

I am in the process of setting up data elements, organisation units, pivot tables, charts, etc for a DHIS 2 instance. I noticed that when I do updates to pivot tables, the changes are not reflected on the dashboard, i.e. the dashboard are not updated even if pivots and charts have been changed. What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DHIS 2 will cache data for pivot tables, charts and maps by default. To disable this you can go to  *apps > settings > general* and set Cache strategy to "No cache". This will disable caching (by setting no cache headers on responses) and is convenient during the configuration phase. Later when the system goes into production caching can be re-enabled.